# Ubuntu lastest kernel update broke my GFX drivers

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, ati, 15.04

So, the latest kernel broke my AMD drivers and forced my system into a Low Graphics Mode on boot up now, the update I got was 3.19.0-26 and I'm now in ttyl consoles now instead of the Ubuntu desktop. I am on 15.04 64 bit but I'm at the end of my rope I have tried to install the regular and updates version of fglrx but I still get LGM when I boot back up. Also, I'm using the drivers provided by additional drivers.

Any help?

Edit: I purged all fglrx drivers from my system using `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` and I got to the greeter but the ubuntu desktop won't load and throws me back at login. Good thing I installed enlightenment desktop, that let's me log-in. I'm going to download and install the drivers from AMD to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Starting the system by live cd I found out in deed that in the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg there were listed old kernels 3.19.0-16 and 3.19.0-15. I changed this to 3.19.0-26 and 3.19.0-25 and could then luckily reboot without any further problems.

Perhaps this is also the case with your system?

Comment: I fixed it and able to login to Ubuntu now, How? I downloaded the lastest Ubuntu 64-Bit .deb files from AMD, and installed them using `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*` which it broke on me after it was done so I used `sudo apt-get -f install` next to try again and finally I used `sudo apt-get upgrade` to grab the lastest fglrx updates for my install and it was all good after that.